# Django's manage.py shell won't indent

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I seem to have run into a strange bug or more likely some setting I am unfamiliar with on my system that is not allowing me to tab when I am in Django's shell (`python manage.py shell` is how I run it).

For obvious reasons this is proving to be annoying since I can't do any loops or conditonals in the shell. If I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> it completes all functions that are available to me, like bash does in a terminal. I've tried just using spaces for my indents but I always get an indentation error.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to get <kbd>tab</kbd> to work in my shell again? (It may be relevant to know that this is on a Ubuntu 9.04 system).

Edit: <kbd>tab</kbd> works fine in the regular pythong shell, it's only in django's that it doesn't.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm came across the same problem, going to try the solution below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing normally when you run `python` it's invoking something like `ipython` instead because the normal stock interpreter does not do tab-completion.  It [should pick up ipython automatically and use it, though](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell).  Try firing up a plain python interpreter (just run `python` at the command line) and running

```
import IPython
```

If you can do that, `manage.py` should use ipython.  If not, maybe reinstall ipython as it would appear that the `IPython` module didn't get properly installed.

Comment: Thanks, reinstalling ipython did it!